# Yerushalmi Horoyos in Shas Vilna

Tags: talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi, shas, masechet-horayot

The Vilna Shas (Bavli) contains the Yerushalmi Horoyos, without meforshim, [following](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14303&st=&pgnum=243) the Bavli version. It does not have this for any other masechta (that I know of). Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so a little bit of digging reveals that the main reason the Yerushalmi was put there was because of the commentary at the bottom of the page, simply titled "פירוש". This commentary is part of the "פירוש הקצר" on the Yerushalmi probably written by Rabbi David Darshan, who was a student of the Ramah (רמ"א). It was originally printed anonymously in the Krakow Yerushalmi edition of 1609, and then the authorship of the commentary was apparently lost to time until a number of decades ago, when [R' Shaul Lieberman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Lieberman) studied a set of Yerushalmi that had handwritten notes in the margins by R' Ze'ev Wolf Rabinowitz.<sup>1</sup> In the introductory page he noted on this mysterious commentary:

> "אף כי העלים את שמו בתחלתו הנה גלה אותו בתוכו בנזיר רפ"ו וחתם את שמו "דוד דרשן""([link](https://www.nli.org.il/he/manuscripts/NNL_ALEPH000044244/NLI#$FL77896711))

Translation: "And though he hid his name in the beginning of this [commentary], he revealed it in the middle, in Nazir, at the start of the 6th chapter and signed his name "David Darshan"."<sup>2</sup>

[image: R' Rabbinowitz's note in the margins]

Now, the printers of the Vilna Shas were simply copying what previous printers of Bavli Horayot had done, which is to add the Yerushalmi Horayot with the anonymous commentary at the bottom. This was first done by the פפד"מ (Frankfurt am Main) printing of 1720 (see [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42036&st=&pgnum=28)) by R' Yehudah Aryeh Leib, originally from Amsterdam. I couldn't find any explanation that he himself wrote for why he did that, but [Rabbi Yissachar Tamar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A8) wrote in his introduction to his commentary on the Yerushalmi, עלי תמר, p. 7:

> "ואין להביא בחשבון גמרא דבני מערבא על הוריות עם פירוש הקצר של דפוס קראקא. שהיא הוספה מאוחרת בדפוס פפד"מ ת"פ ע"י הרב רבי ליב ז"ל למלא החסרון שאין תוספות על גמרא זו. וכן הדפיס תוספות קצרות שנמצא בכ"י שהיה בידי הרב ר"א איטינגא."

Translation: "And one should not count the gemara of the people of Ma'arava (the Land of Israel) on Horayot with the short commentary by the Krakow Edition (as being similar to the inclusion of Yerushalmi Shekalim to the Bavli). For that is a later addition in the Frankfurt 1720 edition by Rabbi Leib z"l to fill the place of the Tosfot which this tractate lacks. And he also printed short Tosfot that were found in a manuscript that was in the hands of Rabbi A. Itinga."

So it seems that he included the short commentary because it could potentially fill in the gaps of the short Tosfot manuscript he was given by Rabbi Itinga.

---

<sup>1</sup> 'הירושלמי כפשוטו, עמ' ח.

<sup>2</sup> However, compare Rabbi Eliezer Galinsky's essay "זהות כותב כת"י פריס של ה"תורת חטאת" והשלכות מכך", Moriah 421-423 (5778), pp. 338-348 who casts some doubt on the identification.